# Possible to Recover Files from Unbootable Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

I have a Surface Pro 7 running Windows 10 and am running into boot issues. I'm waiting for my case with Microsoft to be escalated but in the meantime am wondering if there's a way for me to recover files off my C drive.  First level support is recommending hardware replacement but I'm hoping to avoid that.

I am able to open a command prompt in the recovery menu (X:\windows\system32) and can view my volumes using the diskpart "list volume" command.  It says that the C volume is healthy.

Is there a way to view the files in the C volume from the X (recovery) volume and copy them to USB (which list volume also recognizes/lists as healthy)?

Comment: Taking out the disk and reading directly from that through another system (and OS) is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dir` command to view files:

- In the prompt, on drive X:\, use `c:` to go to the C drive.
- Type `dir`.
- Use `cd [folder name]` to move to a specific folder, and repeat the `dir` command to see its contents.

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) for more options.

---

You can use the `xcopy` command to copy files, folders, and entire drives:

- To copy an entire drive's contents to your USB drive, use the command format `xcopy [source path] [destination path] /s`, so in this case `xcopy c: u: /s`.
- Use the parameters `/s /e /h` to include subdirectories, empty subdirectories, and hidden and system files, respectively.

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) for more options.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!